# chose the best path for estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

I have a Cartesian grid (100x100) in which some of the points are known (30 out of 10,000) and the rest are unknown. I want to use the known points and estimate the other cells. Is there any philosophies behind the way that I must use the known points to estimate the unknown cells? In other words, does it matter that where I should start the estimation? Generally speaking, I personally prefer to start from the locations where I have the maximum amount of the information rather than a random location that probably I might have one known data. However, there is another school says that I should start from a random location in order to prevent any bias. I am more interested to know your ideas about any differences between these methods. Thanks !

Comment: How many different values may a point have? Almost continuous or highly discrete with only 5 or so possible values or somewhere in between. I suppose the main assumption is that nearby points should have similar values. Is there predictive information other than what's on the grid? Sounds like a mapping problem I worked on some years ago. Many possible approaches depending on answers. Will look for comments later tonight or in the am (CA time)

Comment: I can roughly say that is changes from 1 to 1000. In other words, it is not a discrete property, but it is a continuous variable that has a log-normal distribution.

Comment: How do you define "locations where I have the maximum amount of information"?

Comment: You can simply use a moving window and count the number of the known point in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

A simple scheme I found very effective is to begin by letting each known point 'rule' the territory that is nearer to it than to other points. Various measures of nearness can be used and give somewhat different results. Two possible measures are actual linear distance and squared distance. (Then maybe on a subsequent path figure a way to make the inevitable boundaries have intermediate values.) This method is very naive mathematically, but in the right situation it can give very good results.

An entirely different approach is 'kriging'. Try this as a search word in Google and, with some caution, you can get a lot of authoritative info on what may turn out to be a topic of major interest to you. This method is sophisticated mathematically and take a huge amount of computation. There is a package for R statistical software devoted to the topic. I would trust that and its ancillary materials. Also Cornell. (Wikipedia is probably correct mathematically and historically, but for may taste it hardly hints at the motivation.)

Comment: I am familiar with Kriging as an estimation method, but my question was something else. My question is about the visiting order that these methods use, they usually use a random order and estimate the unknown points while I believe that one should start from the location where we have the maximum information. So, my question is mostly about the order of visiting rather than an estimation method.

Comment: I found some work on visiting path that it can effect on the results. As I mentioned in my post, a random path can yield a different result to a regular path when you use a limited number of data to estimate a large grid.

Comment: People usually use a path when they want to estimate a grid using a limited number of data. Suppose that you have a very large grid (1000x1000) with a some known data (e.g. 200), then one can start from a random point and consider a radius around it and use the known point in that radius to estimate the visiting point. This can be processed until all of the unknown points are estimated. I want to understand the philosophy behind this random path.

Comment: You definitely use the information of the original known points and previously simulated points for the new visiting point. I think comparing the visiting path of these stochastic methods with Markove random based methods in which they use the information of the previously estimated points in a raster path can show what I am asking. Markovian methods start from a corner and use a certain amount of the information, while random path methods use random walk order. So, how does this visiting path can effect on the results?

Comment: I guess it must depend on how long the wandering continues. If it went on long enough it seems any sufficiently flexible wandering process will eventually result in almost all points having the same value. Intuitively, starting from a region of dense information would speed the grand averaging effect. I programmed a game like this once on a 20 x 20 grid just to see how long it would run before everything was alike.

Comment: I will try to make a figure and put it here tomorrow later to make my question more clear.